# VS2013 Not getting notified of extension updates

Tags: visual-studio-2013, notifications, visual-studio-extensions

I've been using VS 2013 and notice that I do not get a toast notification when new extension updates are available.  We had this in VS 2012.  Is anyone else seeing this or know how to get notifications without having to go check for them manually by clicking the updates node in the extensions gallery?

Comment: Extension update notifications work for me in VS 2013. Maybe it fails for a specific extension you use?

Comment: It may be a problem with another extension that seems to be causing conflicts with other extensions as well, I removed it and will see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notifications have been moved to the [Notifications Hub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/09/16/notifications-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx). Click the little flag by the Quick Launch box in the upper right-hand corner.